# mod-rewrite php to html url not indexed

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I am currently using Rewriterule in my .htaccess file to change every .php page on my site to .html. I'm also using it to change search result pages from

```
www.example.com/search_page.php?city=name&state=name&id=1234
```

to something like

```
www.example.com/result-google-friendly-url-1234.html
```

Everything works but when I made the changes, google is now only indexing my index page. I think it might have something to do with the fact I have 2 urls to the same page and google decided not to index either one. Google webmasters says there are 16 pages "not selected" and then says it could be attributed to "canonicalization", which I don't completely understand.

This stuff is very confusing and I have 2 things going on: changing every page extension from php to html and then changing search result pages from ugly php code to clean html. Do I need to do something else like a 301 redirect to tell Google what's going on? Here's my htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^([.a-zA-Z\-]+)([0-9]+)\.html$ search_page.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^(?![^/]+/)(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Never did find a solution to get google to index my site on its own. I did however write a php script that printed out all 7,000 dynamic pages on my site and submitted it as a sitemap on google webmaster tools and that worked. So I guess a sitemap is the real solution.